# How do I grab all sub gameobjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Is there a way to get all sub gameobjects? I was trying `GameObject.Find` but that needs the name as `string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all your child GameObjects like this:

Make a list, tell Unity the type is GameObject.

```
List<GameObject> list = new List<GameObject>();
```

Then traverse the transform of the parent GameObject using a `foreach` loop. Note that in the code we are taking advantage of the fact that [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) has a `gameObject` component.

```
foreach(Transform t in transform)
    list.Add(t.gameObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to loop through your `gameObject.transform`, which will go through every child [Transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) (which you can then access their GameObject from):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void Example() {
        foreach (Transform child in transform) {
            child.gameObject.name = "foo";
            // or do something else with child.gameObject
        }
    }
}
```

Another way would be to use [GetComponentsInChildren](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html), but be aware that this will also return the current object you're calling this from if you're looking for GameObjects.