# Animate 3D object disassembly in Unity3D

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

my question is just about choosing the right approach because i'm not sure about the solution.

i got 3d model in my project, at some point i want to show animated disassembly , the object is made of somthing like 200 pieces.
so animating with keyframe one by one is time consuming.
the animation i'm looking for is like explosion from the center of the object so the parts will just move out of its center.

example image:
[image]

what would you do?
what is the best way to manage such task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would code it. Maybe I am biased because I am a programmer, but animating it would be a pain.

So I would import the model into Unity3d. Then I would grab all the parts and store them in a list. Once I have the 200 parts then I can do anything I want to them.

I would then proceed to attach rigibodies and box colliders to them all -- this can be done programmatically. Then you can initiate the explosion by adding a velocity to each part. If you want to be fairly realistic and have something that is fairly random you can give each object mass and then use the equation `F=ma` for the explosion. That is, each part will get different acceleration depending on the mass they have.

Comment: sound very reasonable.
i attached a c# script to the root scene, create local variable called model, load it like so: 
model = Instantiate(Resources.Load("ModelName"));
now how can i extract the parts to an array ?

Comment: Since you have `model` keep that reference and use the `foreach` loop found in this link to populate the list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24501703/how-do-i-grab-all-sub-gameobjects/24501865#24501865