# Visualizing 3D model disassembly in SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I’m trying to create an illusion of disassembling a 3D model using SceneKit. It should look something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ74c.jpg):

Assuming the model is of a piece of machinery that consists of many small parts, I would like to animate the model’s parts being “pulled apart" similar to the *Disassemble All* button in the demo below:

https://camentos.github.io/dtool

It seems to me I need to somehow create an "explosion" from the center of the object so the parts will move out away from the center, but I have no idea in which direction the force should be applied for this. Should the force value, direction and mass values be different for all parts of the model?

What I do so far is traverse all children of the model, attach a physics body of type *.dynamic* to them, give them a mass, and apply a force to all children one by one. To create the illusion of parts frozen in the air after disassembling, I use a timer to clear all forces on the parts after a few milliseconds to stop them from flying away completely.

A similar solution was suggested as an answer here:

[Animate 3D object disassembly in Unity3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279198/animate-3d-object-disassembly-in-unity3d)

I tried applying *F=ma* as a force to all parts using gravity and assigning a random mass to each part, but when the model is very large, the parts move in a very jittery/laggy way, and if the model is smaller, they just fly away completely.

```
        let physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
        node.physicsBody = physicsBody
        let randomMass = Float.random(in: 1..<10)
        node.physicsBody?.mass = CGFloat(randomMass)
        let force = Double(randomMass)*(9.8)
        let direction = SCNVector3(0, force, 0)
        node.physicsBody?.applyForce(direction, asImpulse: true)
        node.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false



        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) {
            node.physicsBody?.clearAllForces()
            node.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        }
```

I’m having trouble with coming up with the right values for the force, direction and mass. So far giving each part a huge mass (and the same mass for all) and applying a very small force seems to be working better, but I’m not sure I’m in the right path.

Is using hard-coded pre-determined values according to each model in question the right way to handle this? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the physics engine I would sort and align the nodes based on their bounding boxes and their initial positions. It would be easy to put them all in a row in x direction and set the distance between them according to the x size of the bounding box. If you want it animated you can use the move actions.